# Magento website getting error after login to admin panel

Tags: magento-1.8, admin-panel

We are facing below error after login to the admin panel.

http://kopanaacreations.com/admin

[image]

Comment: Your site has been hacked, see also for example https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Login-page-error-please-check/td-p/16702

Answer (score 2):

I guess your magento instance got compromised.
[There is no `local.php` file in the skin folder](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/skin).
And all the `eval`s in the error message point to the same thing.
You should delete the `local.php` file from the `skin` folder and look in your code for something that is calling that file.
You can even take a clean version that you are using ([from here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/releases)) and compare it with your instance to see what files may be modified.

Comment: If i remove my local.php website als o stopped working. Is there any more suggestions.

Comment: did you compare all your files with a clean version of magento?